# CSS3 box-sizing 50% width

Tags: css

Unless I completely do not understand the `box-sizing` property... why aren't those two DIVs next to each other?

http://jsfiddle.net/MK7Fs/

With `box-sizing: border-box;` shouldn't the padding, margin, and border "cut in" to the 50% width and ultimately end up with 100% width and with enough room to fit both DIVs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Margin is not added in when using `box-sizing : border-box`. If you remove the left/right margins your boxes line-up on the same line.

I also noticed your `<div>` elements have white-space between the first one's closing tag and the second's one opening tag. When using `display : inline-block` this will add space between the elements and they won't line up on the same line.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MK7Fs/1/

`box-sizing` Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Some reading on the space between `display : inline-block` elements: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I didn't know the thing about `inline-block` elements next to each other. That is useful to know.

Answer (score 2):

As Jasper said, margin is not added when using `box-sizing: border-box`. This day and age, however, we've got a new tool in our toolbox: `calc`.

You can give the boxes `width: calc( 50% - 40px );` (assuming you've got a total of 40px of margin).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/htwj/yzh7zg25/

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how `border-box` works. The `box-sizing` property will at most constrain the *padding* and *border* boxes of an element to its contents width & height.

The definition of the `border-box` value as stated in the [Basic UI Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0):

> Any padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified width and height. The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified ‘width’ and ‘height’ properties.